# Rangy: Can I improve the performance when restoring multiple character ranges for highlighting?

Tags: javascript, rangy

I am using [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) to help with some text highlighting functionality in a website. In short, the user can select some text, highlight the text (via button click), and the user can create multiple highlights this way.

The highlights are saved to a database, and at any point in the future the user can re-load the highlights.

However, I have a performance issue when using the `restoreCharacterRanges` which is part of the "TextRange" module. This performance issue becomes much more noticeable when there are more highlights to load.

Currently, I am using some code similar to below (just to point out, it works exactly how I want, it just isn't fast enough):

```
function LoadHighlight(start, end){
    var selectionRanges = [];
    selectionRanges.push({
        "characterRange": {
            "start": start,
            "end": end
        }
    });

    var selection = rangy.getSelection();

    selection.restoreCharacterRanges(myElement, selectionRanges);

    highlighter.highlightSelection(highlightClass, selection);
}
```

With the code example above, the performance issue occurs during the `selection.restoreCharacterRanges` call. It takes about 0.6 seconds to run in my test.

Now, when loading multiple highlights, I expectedly get this 0.6 second hit for each one, and this can quickly add up.

Is there something I can do to load multiple highlights more efficiently? Maybe with one call to `restoreCharacterRanges`?

I have attempted to push multiple selections to the `selectionRanges` array, but this seems to have undesired effects when the `highlightSelection` call is made (i.e. it only highlights the first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the `serialize()` and `deserialize()` ([demo](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/highlighter.html)) methods of the Highlighter for this. I recently added a more performant way of serializing ranges to the Highlighter that also removes the dependency on the TextRange module, which I have to admit is desperately slow for a lot of tasks.

Comment: hmmm... what if I need the "visible character" offsets provided by TextRange? I actually use them for something else, but I guess I only need to calculate them when I first create the highlight. Do you think if I use `saveCharacterRanges` and `serialize` at creation time, I could get away with just using `deserialize` at load time? Perhaps I will have a play with that

Comment: Actually, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734641/rangy-creating-a-new-highlight-is-remembering-the-old-highlight) might cause me a problem trying to serialize multiple highlights at the same time :(

Comment: This is obviously the correct answer from a Rangy perspective, however for my specific needs I ended up writing my own save/load functionality using the data from the native browser selection object. probably a similar approach to rangy (counting visible chars for all nodes) but I understand my way more, so therefore can make it work better for me :)

Comment: @tim-down - I'm not able to use serialize and deserialize in iframe. I also tried saving normal selection data to JSON but while restoring it creates problems. My detail question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569778/issue-with-rangy-saveselection-data-in-json-format